# select from Dictionary finds value but select from ConcurrentDictionary does not

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dictionary, parallel-processing, concurrentdictionary

Today i was doing some tests with the ConcurrentDictionary and Dictionary:

```
class MyTest
{
    public int Row { get; private set; }
    public int Col { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public MyTest(int row, int col, string value)
    {
        this.Col = col;
        this.Row = row;
        this.Value = value;
    }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        MyTest other = obj as MyTest;
        return base.Equals(other);

    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Col.GetHashCode() ^ Row.GetHashCode() ^ Value.GetHashCode());
    }

}
```

Using the Entity above i created and filled a ConcurrentDictionary and a Dictionary and tried the code below:

```
    ConcurrentDictionary<MyTest, List<MyTest>> _test = new ConcurrentDictionary<MyTest, List<MyTest>>();
    Dictionary<MyTest, List<MyTest>> _test2 = new Dictionary<MyTest, List<MyTest>>();

        MyTest dunno = _test.Values.AsParallel().Select(x => x.Find(a => a.Col == 1 && a.Row == 1)).FirstOrDefault();
        MyTest dunno2 = _test2.Values.AsParallel().Select(x => x.Find(a => a.Col == 1 && a.Row == 1)).FirstOrDefault();
```

The first one returns the value but the second one not, what am i doing wrong?

This is the code used to add the values:

```
            _test.AddOrUpdate(cell10,
            new List<MyTest>
            {
                new MyTest(1, 1, "ovpSOMEVALUEValue"),
                new MyTest(1, 2, "ocpSOMEVALUEValue")
            },
            (key, value) => value = new List<MyTest>());

        _test2.Add(cell10,
            new List<MyTest>
            {
                new MyTest(1, 1, "ovpSOMEVALUEValue"),
                new MyTest(1, 2, "ocpSOMEVALUEValue")
            }
            );
```

Comment: Please post the code that is used to add values to the dictionaries.

Comment: _test.AddOrUpdate(cell10, new List<MyTest> { new MyTest(1, 1, "ovpSOMEVALUEValue"), new MyTest(1, 2, "ocpSOMEVALUEValue") }, (key, value) => value = new List<MyTest>()); And for Regular Dictionary: _test2.Add(cell10, new List<MyTest> { new MyTest(1, 1, "ovpSOMEVALUEValue"), new MyTest(1, 2, "ocpSOMEVALUEValue") });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `AddOrUpdate`, and your third parameter is that it should create a new empty list, thus the result is that you end up with an empty list. I am guessing that somewhere before this line of code you are adding an entry with the same key.

Also notice that the `Equals` function is incorrect. You are comparing on reference, not on the actual values you use in the `GetHashCode`. I suggest you use the default template for overriding Equals:

```
     protected bool Equals(x other) {
        return Row == other.Row && Col == other.Col && string.Equals(Value, other.Value);
     }

     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((x) obj);
     }

     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
        unchecked
        {
           var hashCode = Row;
           hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Col;
           hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ (Value != null ? Value.GetHashCode() : 0);
           return hashCode;
        }
     }
```